# converting req.body to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a file input to upload multiple images and saving them to MongoDB, but the images uploaded to me as a string, I need to upload them with an array. I update it with the server code...

```
router.post('/multiple-upload',uploadImages,resizeImages,getResultImages , (req, res, next) => {
     const thing = new Thing({
       filename: req.body.filename,
       images: req.body.images
    
     });
     thing.save().then(
       () => {
         res.status(201).json({
           message: 'Post saved successfully!'
         });
       }
     ).catch(
       (error) => {
         res.status(400).json({
           error: error
         });
       }
     );
   });
```

```
const uploadFiles = upload.array('images', 10);

exports.uploadImages = (req, res, next) => {
  uploadFiles(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      if (err.code === 'LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE') {
        return res.send('Too many files to upload !');
      }
    } else if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    }

    next();
  });
};
```

```
exports.resizeImages = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.files) return next();

req.body.images = [];
  await Promise.all(
    req.files.map(async (files,i) => {
      
     // const filename = files.originalname.replace(/\..+$/, '');
      const newFilename = `tour-${files.originalname}-${Date.now()}-${i + 1}.jpeg`;

      await sharp(files.buffer) 
        .resize(640, 320)
        .toFormat('jpeg')
        .jpeg({ quality: 90 })
        .toFile(`upload/${newFilename}`);
       
      req.body.images.push(newFilename);
  // console.log(req.body.images);

 
  


 


    })
  );

  next();
};
```

```
exports.getResultImages = async (req, res,next) => {
  if (req.body.images.length <= 0) {
    
    return res.send(`You must select at least 1 image !`);
    

  }
 
  const images = req.body.images.map((image) => '' + image + '').join(', ');
 // res.status(200).json(req.body.images)
 req.body.images = images;
  res.locals.images = images;
  console.log();
  next();
  return res.json(req.body.files);
  // res.status(200).json({
          
  //          data:{
  //           images 
  //          }
  //      });
  

  
};
```

I have a file input to upload multiple images and saving them to MongoDB, but the images uploaded to me as a string, I need to upload them with an array. I update it with the server code...

Comment: if you need to "upload as an array" and they're "uploading as a string" ... perhaps it's the client side code that is doing the wrong thing? who knows, you've shown server code

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(req.body.images)` inside this post handler?

Comment: tour-flowers.jpg-1628615995903-3.jpeg, tour-desert.jpg-1628615995895-1.jpeg, tour-flower.jpg-1628615995903-2.jpeg.

Comment: and I need it as array

Comment: I update the code with the server-side API @BRAVO.

Comment: Maybe `.split(",")` helps you?

Comment: it shows (split is not a function)

Comment: but I delete `.join(', ')`

Comment: thanks, @J.F you gave me the Idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works with me by deleting `join(', ')`

in this line    `const images = req.body.images.map((image) => '' + image + '').join(', ');`